# spring integration http outbound adapter not resolving properties

Tags: spring-integration

We are using http outbound adapter to make http get request and we want to read URL from properties file as it changes from envt to envt. We also append some other path to this url using message payload but then it is giving us this error message "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Map has no value for URL". All we need is read base url from properties file and generate final url with payload.

Here is our sample config looks like

```
    <int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
                           url="${url}/{payload}"
                           http-method="GET"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                           >

</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Comment: have you tried property-placeholder `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:my.properties"/>`

Comment: Yes, we do have other props which are being resolved except this one. Strange thing is, if I remove "payload" portion from http adapter and just put url place holder then it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `{payload}` in your URL is an *URI variable* and it can't be resolved automatically. See how it works:

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uri).buildAndExpand(uriVariables)
```

Where `uriVariables` is a `Map` for those URI variables.

So, in your case the expected configuration must be like this:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
                       url="${url}/{payload}"
                       http-method="GET"
                       expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
       <int-http:uri-variable name="payload" expression="payload"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

More information you can find in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/http.html#http-namespace).